How to send concurrent message to client on single connection SignalR
Our application use SignalR to retrieve data from a hub. Each client establishes a single connection at a time.
On the client side, we can invoke multiple methods on the server concurrently by adjusting the MaximumParallelInvocationsPerClient configuration.
Upon method completion, the server utilizes the SendAsync method to transmit data back to the original caller.
However, we've encountered an issue where the data being sent back is quite large, currently it will send data sequences one after one, resulting in a slowdown of our application.
(For example, if I have 2 methods that take 1 minute, it will take me 2 minutes to complete).
In addition, if this process takes longer than 30 seconds (the default server timeout), the connection will reconnect.
I expected server send data concurrent back to client via single connection.
Is my implementation correct?
Are there any configurations or workarounds available that would enable concurrent data transmission to clients through a single connection?
Or we must use multiple connections to achieve it?
Thank you for your assistance.
